# Laravel 5: Alternative for Eloquent's 'orWhere' method for querying collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I have a collection of products (`$this->products`) which I'm getting as a result of a Model query and I want to filter it by some of its attributes values. The problem is that Laravel doesn't have a method like `orWhere` for collections like Eloquent does for querying models. Also I want to use the `LIKE %{$searching_for}%` wildcard and I'm not sure how to use it (if possible at all) to filter my collection.

This is the code I tried to filter my collection with which obviously throws an `Exception` that `orWhere` method doesn't exist:

```
$products = $this->products
        ->where("field1", "LIKE %{$searching_for}%")
        ->orWhere("field2", "LIKE", "%{$searching_for}%")
        ->orWhere("field3", "LIKE", "%{$searching_for}%")
        ->orWhere("field4", "LIKE", "%{$searching_for}%");
```

I'd like to query the Model directly but I just store the `$products` collection in Session so I can use it anywhere I need, I don't want to query the database too often so I'm searching for a solution to somehow filter the existing collection.

Comment: Yeah you'll need to write this type of logic by yourself. Make use of [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods) methods (you'll probably need `->filter`), but they don't provide full SQL-like queries.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->products()->where(...)->orWhere(...)->get();`? `$this->products` is trying to access a property, but `$this->products()` would be trying to access the `public function products(){ ... }` method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Similar to how Saravanan suggests doing it try this:

```
$products = $this->products->filter(function($product) use ($searching_for) {
    return strstr($product->field1, $searching_for) ||
           strstr($product->field2, $searching_for) ||
           strstr($product->field3, $searching_for) ||
           strstr($product->field4, $searching_for);
})
```

It is making sure to assign the filtered collection to a variable. It is also using `strstr` as an alternative to `stripos` though i doubt that is the cause of the issue.

Comment: It worked with both `collect($this->products)->filter()` and `$this->products->filter()` but didn't using `stripos`, only with `strstr` and seems that `strstr` is case sensitive while `stripos` is not case sensitive.

Comment: It worked with `stristr` which is `strstr`'s alternative but is case-insesitive, just like `stripos`. I'll mark your answer as accepted since it had lead me to use `stristr`.

Answer (score 11):

Try using laravel collection's filter method.

```
collect($this->products)->filter(function($value) use ($search) {
    return (stripos($value->field1, $search) || 
        stripos($value->field2, $search) ||
        stripos($value->field3, $search) ||
        stripos($value->field4, $search));
});
```

Here $search is the value that you wanted to search.

Comment: For some reason the result of that code is an empty collection no matter if the search terms matches the field values or not. The code looks correct to me though...

Comment: Your code was mostly correct but Spholt's answer based on yours solved my problem. Thank you anyway!